# Cannot import java.time package

Tags: java, package, java-time

I'm using NetBeans.  I'm trying to `import java.time.*`, but NetBeans (and DrJava) insists this doesn't exist.  I've installed JDK 8, but I don't know how to make the program find java.time. Help!

Edit:

For whatever it's worth, I see in the preferences that "source" is JDK 7, but I don't know how to set it to JDK 8 (there's no option for that).

NetBeans about:

> - Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0 (Build 201403101706)
> - Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.0 Patch 1.1
> - Java: 1.7.0_09; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.5-b02
> - Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_09-b05
> - System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
> - User directory: C:\Users\Mikhail Firer\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0
> - Cache directory: C:\Users\Mikhail Firer\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0

Comment: try to set project level to java 8.

Comment: Please post the content of Help->About

Comment: You are using java 1.7.0 this is java 7 not 8. To set jdk go to tools>java plateform.

Comment: In your project properties, in the *Sources* section, verify that the *Source/Binary Format* is JDK8, and in the *Libraries* section, check that the *Java Platform* is also JDK8

Answer (score 3):

java.time package is only available in Java 8, and you're apparently compiling your code using Java 7

Answer (score 1):

Working for my. Sorry for my english

1. Rigth click in your proyect and select the option **Properties**
2. In the dialog select **Build** > **Compiling**
3. In the rigth side select JDK 8 o **Manager Platform** and **Add Platform** and **Java Standard Edition** then select your JDK 8 directory